# User control's property loses value after a postback

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

This is the HTML. I have a repeater that contains a user control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpNewHire" runat="server">
 <HeaderTemplate>
  <table>            
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
     <td>
         <user:CKListByDeprtment ID = "ucCheckList" 
          DepartmentID= '<%# Eval("DepID")%>' 
          BlockTitle = '<%# Eval("DepName")%>' 
          runat = "server"></user:CKListByDeprtment>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
   </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

DepartmentID is a property that I defined inside the **user control**.

```
int departmentID;

public int DepartmentID
{
  get { return departmentID; }
  set { departmentID = value; }
}
```

And this is how I am trying to access it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int test = departmentID;
}
```

When the page loads for the first time, **departmentID** has a value. However, when the page Posts back, that value is always **0**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All variables (and controls) are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. So you need a way to persist your variable, e.g. in the `ViewState`.

```
public int DepartmentID
{
    get {
        if (ViewState["departmentID"] == null)
            return int.MinValue;
        else 
            return (int)ViewState["departmentID"]; 
    }
    set { ViewState["departmentID"] = value; }
}
```

The MSDN Magazine article "Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application" is useful, but it's no longer viewable on the MSDN website. It's in the April 2003 edition, which you can [download as a Windows Help file (.chm)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineApril2003en-us.chm). (Don't forget to bring up the properties and unblock the "this was downloaded from the internet" thing, otherwise you can't view the articles.)

Comment: Make sense. I was using the variable departmentID all over the class. What do I use instead? The property, i.e. DepartmentID?

Comment: @Richard77: Yes, thats the reason why you should prefer properties over fields. You can change the implementation later. Make fields always private.

Comment: Make sense. No wonder, knowing ASP.NET page's life cycle is one of the top questions during job interview. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Change your property to use viewstate

```
int departmentID = 0;
public int DepartmentID
{
  get { 
         if(ViewState["departmentID"]!=null)
         { departmentID = Int32.Parse(ViewState["departmentID"]); }; 
         return departmentID;
      }
  set { ViewState["departmentID"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: This will blow if `ViewState["departmentID"]` is null. Edit: it will still blow after your edit ;)